# Access boost::mapped_region data directly?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, boost

In the below code:

```
file_mapping fm(FilePath, read_only); 
mapped_region region(fm,read_only);
char* const data = static_cast<char *>(region.get_address());
for(size_t n=0; n<region.get_size(); ++n){
    cout << data[n];
}
```

is there any way to access characters from the mapped memory without needing to create the `data` array?

EDIT code refers to `using namespace boost:interprocess;`

Answer (score 0):

The `data` "array" is not actually created as an expensive allocation or copy - it's merely a pointer to the virtual memory space the OS uses to represent the file contents in memory.  So that's a bit of bookkeeping but no actual significant work.

When you first access it (i.e. data[0]), the OS pages in the first block of file using optimised routines more efficient than C++ streams or C's (f)read.  Good OS'es would also preload the second & subsequent blocks and silently drop old used blocks, so managing physical memory efficiently whilst being faster than you'd expect.  Just make sure your file fits in your free virtual memory space - usually only a problem for 1+ GB files in 32-bit code.

So no, there's no other way - wanted or known - of accessing the contents.  (I'm discounting re-opening the file using standard I/O routines!)